# Extending a class that its name is generated in a mixin

Tags: css, sass, less

This question applies to both SASS and LESS.

I have a bunch of classes that are generated with mixins.
Inside my SASS or LESS code I want to extend those classes.
In LESS it doesn't work complaining that no such class exists (the classes show up in CSS, but obviously they are not in LESS code).
I found [this feature request](https://github.com/less/lesscss.org/issues/95) so I guess LESS doesn't support it.
How about SASS?

Example (LESS but I'll switch to SASS if it can do that):

```
.errorLevels(@x){
  .level-@{x} {
    font-size: unit(8 + @x,px);
  }
}

.errorLevels(1);
.errorLevels(2);
.errorLevels(3);

.seriousError {
  &:extend(.level-1);
}
```

I expect:

```
.level-1 {
  font-size: 9px;
}
.level-2 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.level-3 {
  font-size: 11px;
}

//this part is missing from output
.seriousError {
  font-size: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Oh yes :) The code is too large to copy/paste here, but that link I provided has a shorter description and code example.

Comment: Well, if it's only just one property (i.e. `font-size`) then you can use mixins instead of `extend`. Less supports using dynamically generated classes as mixins since v1.6.0.

Comment: That doesn't look like Sass.

Comment: you are right. it is LESS but I'll change to SASS if it can achieve the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following to extend a class that was generated in a mixin:

```
@mixin classGenerator {
    .error {
        color: red;
        font-size: 9px;
    }
}

@include classGenerator;

.seriousError {
    @extend .error;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

**EDIT**

According to the changes in your question:

```
@mixin errorLevels($x){
  .level-#{$x} {
    font-size: #{12 + $x}px
  }
}

@include errorLevels(1);

.seriousError {
  @extend .level-1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your example works fine in LESS as well. So I added an example to the question to clarify the exact issue: the name of the class is also generated using the mixin.

Comment: Yep! We have a winner. I have resisted switching to SASS (because LESS is more similar to CSS). But this single feature is enough for me to switch.